# How to make each Card the same size in my Material Grid

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I learn React and following this [tutorial](https://reactgo.com/material-ui-react-tutorial/) but even I have the same code the result is not the same. From the tutorial I want to have a Grid like this:

[Image from the Tutorial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3K9F1.png)

But what I get is this:

[Image from my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbiiZ.png)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/styles';
import { Grid, Paper, Typography } from "@material-ui/core";
import Card from "@material-ui/core/Card";
import CardActionArea from "@material-ui/core/CardActionArea";
import CardContent from "@material-ui/core/CardContent";
const images = require.context('../../public/images', true);

export class Posts extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {

    }
    render() {
        const { classes } = this.props;
        return (
            <div style={{ marginTop: 20, padding: 30 }}>
                <Grid container spacing={40} justify="center">
                    {this.props.books.map(post => (
                        <Grid item key={post.title} Box width={1 / 4}>
                            <Card>
                                <CardActionArea>
                                  
                                    <CardContent>
                                        <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
                                            {post.title}
                                        </Typography>
                                        <Typography component="p">{post.description}</Typography>
                                        <Typography component="p">{post.author}</Typography>
                                        <Typography component="p">{post.genre}</Typography>
                                        <Typography component="p">{post.publish_date}</Typography>
                                        <Typography component="p">{post.price}</Typography>

                                    </CardContent>

                                  
                                </CardActionArea>
                            </Card>
                        </Grid>
                    ))}
                </Grid>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        books: state.reducer.booksList
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(withStyles(styles)(Posts));
```

What am I doing wrong? I think it´s the text that forces the Card to be bigger but I have not read about how to constraint text if that is possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply style to the cards

```
 var cardStyle = {
    display: 'block',
    width: '30vw',
    transitionDuration: '0.3s',
    height: '45vw'
}
```

And in your CardStyle you can apply the above styling by

```
  <Card style={cardStyle}>
                <CardHeader
                  title="URL Avatar"
                  subtitle="Subtitle"
                  avatar="https://placeimg.com/800/450/nature"
                />
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `post.title`s are long. You can use a [fluid grid](https://material-ui.com/components/grid/#fluid-grids). Remove `Box width={1 / 4}` from `Grid item`.

```
<Grid item key={post.title} xs={3}>
```

`xs={3}` to scale to 1/4 of the container.

You can also set noWrap property to show an ellipsis for long titles instead of a wrapping.

```
<Typography noWrap ...>
  {post.title}
</Typography>
```